# imagemagic's convert command doesnt seem to work correctly on my system

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, terminal, imagemagick-convert

I was trying to batch reduce the quality of some of the images on my system stored at the location

```
~/sandboxArea/MainCam
```

and I ran the following command

```
for i in $(ls ~/sandboxArea/MainCam); do convert $i -quality 30 ~/sandboxArea/converted/$i; done
```

and the above command worked and all the files were first reduced in size and then put into the "~sandboxArea/converted" folder

Then I again tried to reduce the quality of images stored at the location

```
~/sandboxArea/SecondCam
```

and ran the above command after making the required changes as below

```
for k in $(ls ~/sandboxArea/SecondCam); do convert $k -quality 30 ~/sandboxArea/convertedB/$k; done
```

and it gave me the following errors:

```
convert-im6.q16: no images defined `/home/mohit/sandboxArea/convertedB/IMG_5682.JPG' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3258.
convert-im6.q16: unable to open image `IMG_5683.JPG': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2701.
convert-im6.q16: no images defined `/home/mohit/sandboxArea/convertedB/IMG_5683.JPG' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3258.
convert-im6.q16: unable to open image `IMG_5684.JPG': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2701.
convert-im6.q16: no images defined `/home/mohit/sandboxArea/convertedB/IMG_5684.JPG' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3258.
convert-im6.q16: unable to open image `IMG_5685.JPG': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2701.
convert-im6.q16: no images defined `/home/mohit/sandboxArea/convertedB/IMG_5685.JPG' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3258.
```

I tried multiple ways of fixing this issue and also checked the official website of imagemagic.org but there is nothing mentioned about this issue.

Is this a bug? As this command worked once but fail to worked again.

Also, I deleted the files that were previously saved in the "converted" folder to check if the command will work again. And it failed there too. So the same command once worked and the other time it didn't.

Can someone please help. I have about 8000+ images with each about 7-9MB and all these images are eating up a lot of space. Just wanted to save some space on my HDD

Thanks in advance. If anyone needs more clarification please do let me know.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an easier way to reproduce your problem:

```
$ ls ~/tmp
foo.jpg

$ convert foo.jpg bar.jpg
convert-im6.q16: unable to open image `foo.jpg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2874.
convert-im6.q16: no images defined `bar.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3258.
```

The issue is that even though you do have a file `foo.jpg` on the system, it is in a different directory, so you can't access it without qualifying the name. In this case, you can instead run:

```
$ convert ~/tmp/foo.jpg c
(success, no output)
```

Alternatively, you can change the current directory to where `foo.jpg` is:

```
$ cd ~/tmp
$ convert foo.jpg ~/Downloads/bar.jpg
(success, no output)
```

A better loop would iterate over globs and quote properly to robustly handle spaces and similar in filenames:

```
for path in "$HOME/sandboxArea/SecondCam"/*
do
  convert "$path" -quality 30 "$HOME/sandboxArea/convertedB/${path##*/}"
done
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I ran the commands from the directory [ ~/sandboxArea/ ] and this directory contain the other directories "converted" "convertedB" "MainCam" "SecondCam". I'm afraid I didn't fully understand what you mean. Also why the command worked previously and then it failed?  If there is a genuin problem then it shouldn't work in the first place.

Comment: But yes the solution you provided worked, so thanks again. :-)

Comment: One question though: what does ${path##*/} expands to?

Comment: If you are in `~/sandboxArea` and you want to reference a file `~/sandboxArea/SecondCam/IMG_5684.JPG` then you can't do that with just `IMG_5684.JPG`. This will only look for `~/sandboxArea/IMG_5684.jpg`. It will not look in any subdirectories to try to find `~/sandboxArea/SecondCam/IMG_5684.jpg`. Instead you have to specify which subdirectory the file is in relative to the current directory, e.g. `SecondCam/IMG_5684.JPG`. The first time you were probably in `~/sandboxArea/SecondCam` and therefore didn't need any qualifiers to access `IMG_5684.JPG`

Comment: `${path##*/}` removes the longest prefix matching `*/`, so effectively it gets only the filename in path (similar to `basename`). For example, if `path=/home/foo/sandboxArea/SecondCam/IMG_5684.JPG` then `${path##*/}` is `IMG_5684.JPG`

Comment: Wow.. very nicely explained. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had different problem with this command:

```
convert -verbose fractal-noise-8192x8192.png -compress none noise-8192x8192.tif
```

It turned out to be policy.xml file and memory (or map?) limit.
I increased both 8 times, cause on Ubuntu 20.04 they were 256MiB/512MiB.

EDIT: another problematic command, I increased limits even further and disk limit too.

```
convert @list.txt test-dataset-512x512x2000.tif
```